# work vs work out?

Tags: word-usage

Scenario:

Person A and B are working for the same project, A found an issue and asked B to fix.

B did some change, and he wants to ask A for double checking if the change has fixed the issue.

So can B ask as:

> 1. Please check if it works.
> 2. Please check if it works out.

Which one is correct?

Comment: “Please check if it’s fixed” would be a better option.

Comment: @Mohit Great! Thanks!

Comment: @Mohit can you please indicate me the difference between `works` and `works out`? By my understanding, `works` means something takes positive effect; but `works out` means there are some good result. Is it correct?

Comment: Works out is usually used like “it worked out well for him” or “let’s check if it works out” or how is it working out for you?”while “works” is usually used as “this machine works well” or “this watch is not working anymore” or “he was working tirelessly in those days”

Comment: I am not an English language expert so don’t know the exact grammatical term here to be used but looks like “work out” is used where there is a solution to be found for a problem, and “works” & its forms are used where there is more traditional usage of the word is expected like if something works or not (like a clock)

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks so much @Mohit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something *works*, it means it *functions correctly*.

When something *works out*, it means it *produces the correct end result*.

You would say a computer 'works' if it turned on okay, for example:

- Turn on the computer and see if it works.

You would say a plan, or a mathematical equation 'works out'. For example:

- Can you work out the answer to this equation?
- I hope your plan works out.

Comment: Crystal clear! Thank you sir!